# Log Forging issue by HP Audit

Tags: java, debugging, logging, slf4j, audit

Is there any difference between

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

public void myMethod(userId){
    if(true){
        LOGGER.warn("User Id = [{}] is not authorized.", userId);
    }
}
```

And

```
private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
private final String notAuthorized = "User Id = [{}] is not authorized.";

public void myMethod(userId){
    if(true){
        LOGGER.warn(notAuthorized, userId);
    }
}
```

As you can see I made String message as private final field. The reason is I use HP Audit and it gives me "Log Forging" warning.Here is how HP Audit gives and example and how to fix it:

Initial(bad) example:

```
    String val = request.getParameter("val");
    try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(val);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            log.info("Failed to parse val = " + val);
    }
```

And modified(good) example:

```
public static final String NFE = "Failed to parse val. The input is required 
   to be an integer value."
    String val = request.getParameter("val");
    try {
            int value = Integer.parseInt(val);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            log.info(NFE);
    }
```

So based on these examples I modified my code as listed above. The only thing is my code uses parameterized arguments(userId). I am not sure if it fixes the issue here. Can someone help me to understand it better? Thanks.

Comment: With the change, HP audit does notcomplain any more?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I was provided .fprfile, I have to commit my changes  and ask them to ship me new file with my changes in it.